# DNS and Subdomain IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, subdomain

I have 2 web apps installed on my IIS, one running as app1.mydomain and other one as app2.mydomain

In the test environment I just copied about two entries pointed to 127.0.0.1

What changes do I have to do in order to put this on production server, I mean on DNS level?

Can I use URL re-write on IIS to avoid changes for DNS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `A` or `CNAME` records mapping both subdomains to the external IP address of your server.

This tells web browsers to go to your server when you go to the subdomain; URL rewriting has nothing to do with this.

Comment: So I have to contact the domain name provider for this? Can I ask them to map *.mydomain to my server ip?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Any decent domain registrar will give you a zone editor to let you do this yourself.